# Force sending emails on port 587

Tags: raspberry-pi, postfix, raspbian

I have an email server that is running postfix and dovecot for emails. Receiving emails works just fine, however my ISP blocks port 25. I'm trying to use either TLS or SSL to avoid this. The problem is that when I try to send an email out, it tries connecting to the external server's port 25.

Relevant log entries:

```
Dec 28 19:32:18 RPI-Email postfix/smtp[14354]: connect to smtp.secureserver.net[68.178.213.37]:25: Connection timed out
Dec 28 19:32:48 RPI-Email postfix/smtp[14354]: connect to mailstore1.secureserver.net[72.167.238.29]:25: Connection timed out
Dec 28 19:32:59 RPI-Email postfix/smtp[14357]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.198.27]:25: Connection timed out
```

Here's my master.cf file:

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master").
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
587      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#
#
#
#smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#587      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       -       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       -       -       0       tlsproxy
#submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
#  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       -       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    fifo  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     fifo  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -   n   n   -   2   pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
```

And this is my main.cf file:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version
# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = <WEBSITE URL>, RPI-Email, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
myhostname = <WEBSITE URL>
home_mailbox = Maildir/
mailbox_command =
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    permit_mynetworks,
    reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks,
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    reject_invalid_helo_hostname,
    reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname,
    reject_unknown_helo_hostname,
    check_helo_access hash:/etc/postfix/helo_access

#Own Research
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_password
```

I've tried all kinds of changes to my master.cf file, but am having zero success so far. How do I go about forcing Postfix to use port 587 instead of port 25 for sending mail? Am I looking in the wrong spot for it?

Comment: Try using `mail.domainyouown.com` instead of trying to break GoDaddy's Policy.  If that soesn't work you need a 3rd party mailserver. 597 is the Exchange Port.

Comment: @eyoung100 Don't jump the gun here, I'm sending a test email TO a GoDaddy account, not FROM a GoDaddy account. As for the rest of your comment, none of that applies. I'm just trying to figure out how to send secure emails via port 587 or 465. My ISP allows this, but blocks the insecure port 25 to prevent mail worms.

Comment: Does [this FreeBSD Diary Entry](http://www.freebsddiary.org/postfix-transport.php) help?

Comment: @eyoung100 unfortunately it does not, since that's for incoming ISP blocks. Mine is outgoing. It's currently trying to go from `Local Server 25 --> ISP 25 --> Remote Server 25` but is being blocked and is thus timing out. My ISP advised me instead do something like this: `Local Server 587 --> ISP 587 --> Remote Server 587` which should work. The problem is that I'm not sure how to do that in postfix, and everything I try reverts back to port 25 on the remote server, which (due to the ISP block) won't work.

Comment: It does this because your ISP is disallowing using port 25 on a residential account...  that tutorial opens port 587.  If that doesnt work you need a commercial account

Comment: It didn't open port 587 for me. Instead, it made the outgoing side of the server entirely inaccessible, even though I gave it my external (and static) IP address instead of the one in the tutorial. I tried TLS, SSL, even no authentication on port 587 for the SMTP side and it failed to connect (or even show in the logs for that matter).

Comment: Do you have a host that will accept all outgoing email from you and deliver it? Where do you have that configured? Or are you hoping that simply replacing port 25 with 587 will magically work (which it will not)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I need to use my ISP's SMTP relay since a few of the email servers I'm hitting don't accept connections from port 587. Some do, but some don't.